# How to scale HTML page for high resolutions?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a website at the moment, and I'm trying to have my page scale responsively with high resolutions.

At the moment, the pages respond nicely to window resizes, but when I try the page out on different resolutions (specifically high resolutions) everything becomes very very tiny.

I want all the elements on the page to scale appropriately for a user if they have large screen sizes.

Here is a JSFiddle of the basic HTML template of my [website](https://jsfiddle.net/jc2ktw89/).

And a code snippet:

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
}

.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-container-vertical {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 1px;
}

.header {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#work-area {
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    margin: 1px;
}

#bars {
    width: inherit;
    height: auto;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#pane-container {
    border: 0.5px solid black;
}

#left-pane {
    width: 20%
}
#centre-pane {
    width: 60%;
}
#right-pane {
    width: 20%;
}

#operation-catalogue-pane, #operation-editor-pane {
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    height: 50%;
}

#canvas-pane {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 70%;
}

#canvas {
    margin: 1px;
    height: calc(100% - 24px);
}

#lower-control-pane {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30%;
    width: calc(100% - 4px);
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#lower-control {
    margin: 1px;
    height: 100%;
}

#workspace-tree-pane {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 40%;
}

#tabs-area {
    height: inherit;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="work-area" class="flex-container flex-container-vertical">
    <div id="bars" class="flex-item">
        <div id="menu-bar" class="header">
            <div class="overflowing-bar">
                <div>
                    <a href="/pixi-test.html">Pixi sandbox</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tool-bar" class="header">
            <div class="overflowing-bar">
                <div>
                    <a href="/pixi-test.html">Pixi sandbox</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pane-container" class="flex-container flex-item">
        <div id="left-pane" class="flex-item flex-container flex-container-vertical">
                <div id="operation-catalogue-pane" class="flex-item">
                    <div id="operation-catalogue-header" class="header">
                        <div id="operation-catalogue-header-title">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="operation-catalogue">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="operation-editor-pane" class="flex-item">
                    <div id="operation-editor-header" class="header">
                        <div id="operation-editor-header-title">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="operation-editor">

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="centre-pane" class="flex-item flex-container flex-container-vertical">
            <div id="canvas-pane" class="flex-item flex-container flex-container-vertical">
                <div id="canvas-pane-header" class="header">
                </div>
                <div id="canvas">
                    <pixi-component id="pixi-component"></pixi-component>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="lower-control-pane" class="flex-item flex-container-vertical">
                <div id="lower-control">
                    <lower-control-component id="lower-control-component" class="flex-container-vertical"></lower-control-component>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-pane" class="flex-item flex-container flex-container-vertical">
            <div id="workspace-tree-pane" class="flex-item">
                <div id="workspace-tree-pane-header">
                    <div id="workspace-tree-pane-header-title">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="workspace-tree">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

You can try and see that all the elements resize nicely when you drag the viewport around. However when I try to view the website at high resolutions, using chrome developer tools, everything is quite small. It's most obvious on the green headers.

What I want to do is modify my CSS to ensure that the page scales appropriately for high resolutions, so I don't get any elements being extremely small. How can I do this?

Edit: Here is my head element

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WorkspacePrototype</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="workspace.png">
    <script src="/assets/pixi.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Are you using the meta viewport element?

Comment: @Rob Yes. I've edited my post to include the head element so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think the technique described in the [link](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/) here will work for your project:

It works with the css scale function and has the big advantage that its scales always no matter how big or small your screen gets.

Comment: Please don't just paste a link as in the future it might not be available anymore. Also, you should really try to explain how to use the procedure and come up with a small code example starting from the sample code provided in the question.